# Find the missing values in Julia like R's is.na function

Tags: r, julia, missing-data

The Julia 1.0.0 [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-R-1) says this about missing values in Julia and R:

> In Julia, missing values are represented by the missing object rather than by NA. Use ismissing(x) instead of isna(x). The skipmissing function is generally used instead of na.rm=TRUE (though in some particular cases functions take a skipmissing argument).

Here is example code in R that I would like to duplicate in Julia:

```
> v = c(1, 2, NA, 4)
> is.na(v)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

(First note that `is.na` is the R function's correct spelling, not `isna` as shown in the quote above, but that is not my point.)

If I follow the documentation's suggestion to use `ismissing` in Julia, I get a different type of result than in R.

```
julia> v = [1, 2, missing, 4]
4-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
  missing
 4

# Note that based on R, I was expecting: `false false true false` 
# though obviously in a different output format.
julia> ismissing(v)
false
```

To duplicate the R code, I seem to have to do something like:

```
julia> [ismissing(x) for x in v]
4-element Array{Bool,1}:
 false
 false
  true
 false
```

That works, but it is not as succinct as `is.na` in R.  Maybe I am missing something.

I also tried:

```
julia> ismissing(v[:])
false

julia> ismissing(v[1:end])
false
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can broadcast `ismissing` with `.`:

```
julia> v = [1, 2, missing, 4]
4-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
 1
 2
  missing
 4

julia> ismissing.(v)
4-element BitArray{1}:
 false
 false
  true
 false
```

Comment: Thanks!  That is exactly what I was missing :).

Comment: I've filed a pull request to fix this: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/29332

Comment: @MilanBouchet-Valat Thanks.