# In Julia find the indices of all missing values in one-dim array

Tags: julia, missing-data

This stack [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52357942/find-the-missing-values-in-julia-like-rs-is-na-function) shows how to return `booleans` for the `missing` values in an array.

For example:

```
julia> A = [1, 2, 3, missing, 4, 5, 6, missing, 7, 8, missing, 9, 10]
13-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  1
  2
  3
   missing
  4
  5
  6
   missing
  7
  8
   missing
  9
 10

julia> ismissing.(A)
13-element BitArray{1}:
 false
 false
 false
  true
 false
 false
 false
  true
 false
 false
  true
 false
 false
```

How do you return their indices?

Comment: Go to https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/ . Press Ctrl + F. Type "find".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the same example, you can do this:

```
julia> A = [1, 2, 3, missing, 4, 5, 6, missing, 7, 8, missing, 9, 10]
13-element Array{Union{Missing, Int64},1}:
  1
  2
  3
   missing
  4
  5
  6
   missing
  7
  8
   missing
  9
 10

# Below are the indices of the missing elements.
julia> findall(ismissing, A)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  4
  8
 11
```

You can also find if any or all elements are `missing`, and the first and last indices:

```
julia> any(ismissing, A)
true

julia> all(ismissing, A)
false

julia> findfirst(ismissing, A)
4

julia> findlast(ismissing, A)
11
```

Comment: It is redundant to write `x->ismissing(x)`, when you should just use `ismissing`. So, in your examples, replace all occurrences of `x->ismissing(x)` with `ismissing`.

Comment: @DNF Wow!  I didn't realize it could be that easy.  Thanks for the comment.